# How to get the source after executing javascript using Autoit

Tags: javascript, autoit

I'm trying to get the HTML code after executing javascript in IE. Here is my code.

```
$url = "http://example.com"
$oIE = _IECreate($url)
Sleep(3000) ;waiting for executing javascript. But useless.
$oFrame = _IEFrameGetCollection($oIE, 0)
$sCode &= _IEPropertyGet($oFrame, "innerhtml") & @CRLF
```

Then, I get this error.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoIt3\Include\IE.au3" (2308) : ==> The requested action with this object has failed.:
$oTemp = $oObject.document.body
$oTemp = $oObject^ ERROR
```

After executing javascript, when I view source in IE, there are HTML code like below.

```
<html>
<head>
...
</head>
<body>
...
</body>
</html>
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

To read the source of the entire page, use _IEDocReadHTML

e.g.

```
$url = "http://example.com"
$oIE = _IECreate($url)
Sleep(3000) ;waiting for executing javascript. But useless.
$sCode &= _IEDocReadHTML($oIE) & @CRLF
```

Comment: This code get javascript code before executing javascript.